# Getting DiscordAPIError[50035] after upgrading to discord.js v14.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I just downloaded discord.js v14 (not the latest release) and I'm getting the error. I can't find what I did wrong but it was working in v13.1.0.

```
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
0.type[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "CHAT_INPUT" is not int.
3.options[0].type[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "USER" is not int.
3.options[1].type[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "STRING" is not int.
4.options[0].type[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "USER" is not int.
4.options[1].type[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "STRING" is not int.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (H:\Projects\Discord\Handler\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (H:\Projects\Discord\Handler\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (H:\Projects\Discord\Handler\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (H:\Projects\Discord\Handler\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:173:18)
    at async H:\Projects\Discord\Handler\handler\index.js:47:13 {
```

If you need to know, here's where the error points to:

```js
await guild.commands.set(slashcmds);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what I did wrong. To people reading this in the future, here's the answer:

Discord has changed from strings to enums, here's what they changed in my case ("+" means added, "-" means deprecated)

```js
+ const { ApplicationCommandType, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');

const command = {
  name: 'ping',
- type: 'CHAT_INPUT',
+ type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  options: [{
    name: 'option',
    description: 'A sample option',
-   type: 'STRING',
+   type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
  }],
};
```

Comment: You might also want to check the rest of the upgrade guide. https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#before-you-start